# Clicking on "Install Ubuntu" does not initiate Ubuntu installation (16.04)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have a Windows 10 pre-installed laptop. I'm planning on installing Ubuntu alongside it (dual booting). So I created a bootable USB using unetbootin. I have configured and performed all the tasks that are required to land me on "Try Ubuntu without installing / Install Ubuntu" black screen. But on pressing "Install Ubuntu", the Ubuntu Desktop shows up, but on pressing the "Install Ubnuntu" icon, NOTHING HAPPENS! The installation process is not triggered.

Please, let me know any alternate solutions to install Ubuntu, if any. I'm not willing to run it on a VM.

[HP Pavilion Series, Windows 10, Intel i5 64-bit, 8 GB RAM]

Comment: Burn Ubuntu to a DVD disk and boot from that disc. You won't have any trouble then. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema Thank you for your comment. I will try that out this time. But should I burn the disk with the iso file in it or the extracted files of the iso?

Comment: Burn the .iso file directly to DVD. See `https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto` for help. Cheers, Al